# og: meta Facebook tags: How to get a tall image to display full

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, og-meta

For some of my `og: meta` tags, I'm using images that are much taller than they are wide - 1920px tall by 1280px wide. This results in a small thumbnail rather than an image that spans the full card.

Other than cropping the photo to a 1.91 to 1 ratio, is there anything I can do to force Facebook Debugger to "auto-crop" this image so that it utilizes the full card space? Would `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` be able to help, or anything else? Or is cropping the only option here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` be able to help, or anything else? Or is cropping the only option here?

Cropping is the only option.

`og:image:width` and `og:image:height` are only used to tell the scraper about the *actual* dimensions of the image, so that in the context of a first share the preview for the user can be rendered more quickly; they can not be used to resize or crop the image.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the insight.